# MySQL - maximum value of minimum value per period

Tags: php, mysql, sqlperformance

**My problem:**

Lets say I need to find the best possibility (the max allotment an item can offer), in a certain period - 10 days for this example.
The user wants to go on a holiday for 5 days.

Example resultset from current query shows the allotment per day:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| Item Id |    Date    | Allotment |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|   10    | 20-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 21-10-2018 |    80     |
|   10    | 22-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 23-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 24-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 25-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 26-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 27-10-2018 |    70     |
|   10    | 28-10-2018 |    100    |
|   10    | 29-10-2018 |    100    |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

**The resultset of the above example is done with the following query:**

```
foreach($arrivalDates as $key => $date) {
            $arrivalDate = $date['from'];
            $departureDate = $date['till'];

            $allotmentSQLArr[] = "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN $arrivalDate AND $departureDate AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration)";
            $whereSqlArr[] = "(
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = $arrivalDate AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = $departureDate AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                )";
        }

        $query = "
            SELECT
                t.fkItemId,
                t.arrival_date,
                SUM(t.total_allotment) as total_allotment
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    ir.fkItemId,
                    ir.id,
                    ea.arrival_date,
                    (ea.allotment * r.max_occupancy) as total_allotment
                FROM 
                    item_room ir
                INNER JOIN
                    room r
                ON 
                    r.id = ir.fkRoomId
                INNER JOIN
                    availability as ea
                ON
                    ea.fkItemRoom = ir.id
                AND
                    ea.arrival_date BETWEEN :begin_date AND :end_date
                AND
                    ea.allotment > 0
                AND 
                    (".implode(' OR ', $whereSqlArr).")
                WHERE
                    (".implode(' OR ', $allotmentSQLArr).")
            ) as T
            GROUP BY
                t.fkItemId, t.arrival_date
        ";
```

**Solution I'm looking for:**
Now I need to know if the item can offer the user a stay for 5 days and has atleast 80 allotment available per day.
For the following periods 20-10-2018 till 24-10-2018, 21-10-2018 till 25-10-2018, 22-10-2018 till 26-10-2018 **the max is 80**. For the period 23-10-2018 till 27-10-2018 **the max is 70**.

In this case the item should be available, because it can offer the user the allotment in at least one period.

My own approach:

```
SELECT
            a.id
        FROM
         tl_item a
         WHERE 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    1
                FROM (
                    SELECT
                        t.fkItemId,
                        t.arrival_date,
                        SUM(t.total_allotment) as total_allotment
                    FROM (
                        SELECT
                            ir.fkItemId,
                            ir.id,
                            ea.arrival_date,
                            (ea.allotment * r.max_occupancy) as total_allotment
                        FROM 
                            tl_item_room ir
                        INNER JOIN
                            tl_room r
                        ON 
                            r.id = ir.fkRoomId
                        INNER JOIN
                            tl_et_availability as ea
                        ON
                            ea.fkItemRoom = ir.id
                        AND
                            ea.arrival_date BETWEEN :begin_date AND :end_date
                        AND
                            ea.allotment > 0
                        AND 
                            ((
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1539853200 AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540458000 AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                ) OR (
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1539939600 AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540544400 AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                ) OR (
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540026000 AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540630800 AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                ) OR (
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540112400 AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540720800 AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                ) OR (
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540198800 AND ea.arrival_possible = 1 AND ((ea.is_maximum IS NULL AND ea.minimum_stay <= :duration) OR (ea.is_maximum = 1 AND ea.minimum_stay = :duration)))
                        AND 
                EXISTS (SELECT fkItemRoom FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date = 1540807200 AND ea.departure_possible = 1)
                ))
                        AND
                            (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN 1539853200 AND 1540458000 AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN 1539939600 AND 1540544400 AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN 1540026000 AND 1540630800 AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN 1540112400 AND 1540720800 AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tl_et_availability ea WHERE fkItemRoom = ir.id AND ea.arrival_date BETWEEN 1540198800 AND 1540807200 AND allotment > 0 HAVING COUNT(ea.fkItemRoom) >= :duration))
                    ) as T
                    GROUP BY
                        t.fkItemId,t.arrival_date
                    )  as B
                WHERE
                    ((arrival_date BETWEEN 1539853200 AND 1540458000 and total_allotment > :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1539939600 AND 1540544400 and total_allotment > :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540026000 AND 1540630800 and total_allotment > :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540112400 AND 1540720800 and total_allotment > :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540198800 AND 1540807200 and total_allotment > :allotment))
                AND
                b.fkItemId = a.id

            )
```

I'm aware that the above will return TRUE if just ONE record matches the criteria. What I need to achieve is that the following line checks if ALL records between these dates have an allotment greater as assigned:

```
WHERE ((arrival_date BETWEEN 1539853200 AND 1540458000 and total_allotment >= :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1539939600 AND 1540544400 and total_allotment >= :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540026000 AND 1540630800 and total_allotment >= :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540112400 AND 1540720800 and total_allotment >= :allotment) OR (arrival_date BETWEEN 1540198800 AND 1540807200 and total_allotment >= :allotment))
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I added a more clear MCVE.

Comment: Um, no you didn't.